# Changing particular range of pixel values to required value in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, windows-forms-designer

I want to change the pixels in an image which are in the range between 140 to 180. So I used the following code. But it's saving original image only, not the changed one. Please help me to convert pixels of the image in between 140 to 180 into 0 (black color). Below my code:

```
public void convertImage(string imag)//some file path
{
    using (Bitmap image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(imag))
    {
        BitmapData data = image.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        IntPtr ptr = data.Scan0;
        int size = data.Stride * image.Height;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

        for (int y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < image.Width; x++)
            {
                if (
                    (140 < bytes[(y * data.Stride) + (x * 3) + 2]) && (180 > bytes[(y * data.Stride) + (x * 3) + 2]) &&
                    (140 < bytes[(y * data.Stride) + (x * 3) + 1]) && (180 > bytes[(y * data.Stride) + (x * 3) + 1]) &&
                    (140 < bytes[(y * data.Stride) + x * 3]) && (180 > bytes[(y * data.Stride) + x * 3])
                    )
                {
                    bytes[(y * data.Stride) + (x * 3) + 2] = (int)0;
                    bytes[(y * data.Stride) + (x * 3) + 1] = (int)0;
                    bytes[(y * data.Stride) + x * 3] = (int)0;
                }
            }
        }

        Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, ptr, bytes.Length);
        image.UnlockBits(data);
        image.Save("sys.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
        image.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Here I am assuming my image is having pixels of grey in between 140 to 180 of each color. Please help me.

Comment: Have you stepped through this in the debugger?  Do you know that you are getting inside the `if` block?

Comment: When you're done, what image are you checking for changes?  The original image or `sys.bmp`?

Comment: Invoque UnlockBits right after your first Marshal.Copy. And additionnally, no need to dispose your image, using statement is there for it.

Comment: @GuillaumeBeauvois, if he calls `UnlockBits` immediately after the first Marshal.Copy, the changed pixel data will never be copied back to the image.  Why would he want that?

Comment: @adv12 The data is copied back to the image with the second Marshal.Copy witch copy the new byte array to the ptr position.

Comment: @GuillaumeBeauvois, there is no guarantee that that pointer remains valid after `UnlockBits`.  That's the whole point of `LockBits` and `UnlockBits`: `LockBits` pins the pixel data in a certain format (which may not even be the image's native format) to a specific memory location until `UnlockBits` is called.

Comment: @subrahmanyeswaraswamymurala, don't forget to mark sasha_gud's answer as accepted if it solves your problem (which I'm guessing it does).

Comment: I used message box inside if block its entering into if block also.

Comment: I am checking sys.bmp for my changes but its same as input original image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace ImageLockMode with **ReadWrite** rather than **ReadOnly**.

```
BitmapData data = image.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
```

Comment: @subrahmanyeswaraswamymurala Thanks! Please marke answer as correct then.